# python : read first 1000 bytes from a unicode string

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have this long unicode string in python. Of this unicode string I want to read first 1000 bytes.

Use case: I'm trying to send the email body content on a mobile number using the plivo API as a text message. This text message take maximum of 1000 bytes.

So I need to truncate first 1000 bytes from the email body content.

How can this be done ?

Comment: People generally expect you to have already tried something yourself; you didn't share any such attempts, making this a basic 'give us the codez' question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the first 1000 **bytes** then you need to encode the Unicode value *first*, as the number of bytes varies with the encoding picked.

Then just slice the first 1000 bytes:

```
encoded = unicodevalue.encode('utf8')
sliced = encoded[:1000]
```

As it happens, the [Plivo Send Message API](http://plivo.com/docs/api/message/#message) requires exactly that; 1000 bytes of UTF-8 encoded data. You *probably* want to truncate the data further to not cut off multi-byte UTF-8 characters:

```
encoded = unicodevalue.encode('utf8')
sliced = encoded[:1000]

while True:
    try:
        sliced.decode('utf8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        sliced = sliced[:-1]  # remove one invalid byte
    else:
        break
```

Comment: And keep in mind this might produce a corrupted string.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I was certainly keeping that in mind; I've updated the post to include a way to remove corrupt data from the end.

Comment: at start of each truncated message there is string of number , why it is coming and how to remove it